# XMLHttpRequest - relative or absolute path?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make HTTP tests in my local server.

On my HTML file, I link `src="scripts/scriptedHTTP.js`:

```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", "file.txt", false);
   req.send(null);
   console.log(req.responseText);
```

I serve on `localhost:8000` with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

`file.txt` is on the same path as `scriptedHTTP.js`

`http://localhost:8000/scriptedHTTP.html` gets me `Error 404`.

If I run `scriptedHTTP.js` with `node`, I get `XMLHttpRequest is not defined`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` will form the request path using the page domain (if you don't set it manually), so in this case you just need to specify the complete path of your **file.txt**:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "scripts/file.txt", false);
req.send(null);
console.log(req.responseText);
```

Note that `XMLHttpRequest` is a feature of web browsers so is not available in **NodeJS**

Comment: 404 error is gone now. but the console on the web browser is blank. if `XLMHttpRequest` is retrieving the file's content, where is it?

Comment: @data_garden that is because you are just making a request (retrieving the data), now you need to handle req.responseText. For example you can add that response as a the innerHTML of a div.

Comment: like this: `var div = document.createElement('div');` `div.innerHTML = req.responseText;` still seeing nothing...